# Circle touching a given line at a point

Tags: geometry, circles

The line $x=y$ touches a circle at a point $(1,1).$ If the circle also passes through the point $(1,-3)$ then find it.

Circle touching a line is $$(x-x_1)^2+(y-y_1)^2+λL=0$$
we get $(x-x_1)^2+(y-y_1)^2+λ(x-y)=0.$

Now according to my textbook, this is the substitution
$(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2+λ(1-1)=0$ and $(1,-3)$ in $x$ and $y.$
But according to the solution in the test from which the question is, the substitution is $(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2+λ(1-(-3))=0$ and $(x, y)= (1,-3).$

How is the second one correct when $(1,-3)$ does not even lie on the line $x=y ?$
OR is the formula in my textbook wrong ?
I referred to other books but they have the same formula as my textbook.

A similar method of substitution has been used to solve many sums of the similar kind in the test.
I do not need a solution.

Comment: You use the word touch, but the problem is asking about the circle being tangent to the line at that point. This means that the radius to that point is perpendicular to the line

Comment: The line is $L=0$.  The other point $(1,-3)$ is not on the line so you can actually determine $\lambda$ from $(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2+\lambda L=0$.

Comment: You're substituting $(1, -3)$ in the equation of circle because it lies on it. You have already taken the condition that it passes through $(1, 1) $.

Answer (score 0):

Tangent: so the line $y = 2 - x$ is a diameter of the circle. The perpendicular bisector of the segment from $(1,1)$ to $(1,-3)$  also passes through the circle center.

[image]

Comment: Isn't it $y=2-x$?   But OP doesn't need a solution.